# How can I prove this inequality? $c\leq x\leq a+b$

Tags: geometry

[image]

Show that if ABC is a right triangle and curve $x$ is inside the ABC triangle then we have

$$c\leq x\leq a+b$$

Do not use integral.

Comment: Please, show your try.

Comment: I don't have any idea to prove this :(

Comment: I would expect anybody at least to think of the triangle inequality even if it is not that helpful, for example...

Comment: with Pythagoras with can show that $c<a+b$ but what can we do with $x$?

Comment: You must assume some property of $x$. Is it convex for example?

Comment: if x=f(y) then f is continuous and one-to-one function

Comment: Integrals??? This is the most basic geometry: triangle inequality and shortest path between two points is straight line. You don't even need a right triangle because it is always true

Comment: @Raffaele how about $x\leq a+b$? how do you show this?

Comment: Axioms: http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fc-2012-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $c\leq x$ is just the statement "the shortest distance between any two points is a straight line." The upper bound $x\leq a+b$ is harder.

So far as I know, there isn't an elementary geometric argument. Suppose the graph curve is rectifiable (let's say with arclength $s$ rather $x$), and let $\gamma(x) = (x,f(x))$ parameterize the curve. Given $\epsilon>0$, the definition of rectifiability implies there are points $0=x_0<x_1<\dotsm< x_n=b$ such that
$$s-\epsilon<\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}d(\gamma(x_i),\gamma(x_{i+1}))$$
where $d$ is distance in $\mathbb{R}^2$. By triangle inequality we have
$$d(\gamma(x_i),\gamma(x_{i+1})) = \sqrt{(x_i-x_{i+1})^2+(f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})^2}\leq |x_i-x_{i+1}|+|f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})|.$$
Moreover, a continuous injective function is monotone (and hence decreasing in our case), so $|x_i-x_{i+1}|=x_{i+1}-x_i$ and $|f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})| = f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})$. Thus
$$s-\epsilon < \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}d(\gamma(x_i),\gamma(x_{i+1}))\leq\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\big(f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})\big) = b+a.$$
Therefore $s<a+b+\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary in our argument, we conclude $s\leq a+b$, as desired.

As an aside, I believe the upper bound should be achievable with a construction similar to that of the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) (whose graph in the unit square is nondecreasing and has length 2).

Comment: Can you define what is a rectifiable curve? I can't understand it :(

Comment: Rectifiable means "a curve where the arclength is a well-defined thing." It's a secret additional assumption to the problem, since we can't say anything if the graph doesn't have a well-defined arclength. An example of something that's not rectifiable would be Bolzano's function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Anyway, a decreasing function (like ours--decreasing follows from continuous+injective after applying IVT) is always rectifiable. Basically because the set of all length approximations is bounded above by $a+b$ (as in our argument) so the supremum exists.